# qml transition not working for custom toolbar component

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I am trying to use transition a custom toolbar style component in qml where I would like to transition the opacity based on the toolbar state. The code is as follows:

```
Rectangle {
    id: toolbar
    color: "gray"
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    height: 48
    opacity: 0
    property bool on: false

    MouseArea { id: region; anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: toolbar.toggle()}

    function toggle() {
        console.log('toggled')
        on = on == true ? false : true
    }

    states : State {
        name: "shown"
        when: on
        PropertyChanges{
            target:toolbar
            opacity: 1
        }
    }

    transitions: Transition {
        NumberAnimation { property: "opacity"; duration: 500 }
    }            
}
```

I always see the `toggled` message but the transition never gets triggered i.e. I was expecting the toolbar to get visible but that never happens.

Comment: I see no toolbars in your code example. Please improve your question so we can run and test it

Comment: @folibis The component is the toolbar...

Comment: You should replace `when: on` with `when: toolbar.on`. You should not use reserved keywords etc. as a variable name (and words that look like keywords too). And you should follow this rule to avoid stupid errors in the future.